# Sometimes out of 5 times, 2-3 times, Threads gets deadlock in waitforsingleobject

Tags: deadlock, semaphore, waitforsingleobject

I have two thread T1 and T2 which tries to print alrenatively through semaphore signaling. Each thread prints 10 times, but sometime, both gets blocked at WaitforSingleObject and does not print anything.
Am i doing something wrong.Can you please let me know how to solve this and get rid of this problem.

```
HANDLE hThreadSemaphore1,hThreadSemaphore2;   
void T1(void *param) {    
    static int i=0;
    ReleaseSemaphore(hThreadSemaphore2, 1, NULL);        
    BOOL success = SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(),1);     
    _tprintf (_T("SetThreadAffinityMask PAssed: %d\n"), GetLastError());    
    if(success ==0) {    
        _tprintf (_T("Setting the Thread Affinity for T1 could not be done\n"));    
    }    
    while(i!=10) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThreadSemaphore2,INFINITE);
        i++;
        printf("Thread 1 is Running %d!\n",i);
        ReleaseSemaphore(hThreadSemaphore1, 1, NULL);
    }      
    _endthread(); 
}
```

T2:

```
void T2(void *param) {
    static int i=0;
    BOOL success = SetThreadAffinityMask(GetCurrentThread(),1); 
    _tprintf (_T("SetThreadAffinityMask PAssed: %d\n"), GetLastError());
    if(success ==0) {
        _tprintf (_T("Setting the Thread Affinity for T1 could not be done\n"));
    }
    while(i!=10) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThreadSemaphore1,INFINITE);
        i++;
        printf("Thread 2 is Running %d!\n",i);
        ReleaseSemaphore(hThreadSemaphore2, 1, NULL);
    }
    _endthread();
}
```

Main

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {  
    unsigned long val1,val2;
    HANDLE handle1,handle2;
    handle1 = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL,0,  (unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *))T1,NULL,0,(unsigned int*)&val1); // create thread
    char SemName[80];
    sprintf(SemName, "ThreadSem_0x%x",val1);
    hThreadSemaphore1 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 5,(LPCWSTR) SemName);

    handle2 = (HANDLE) _beginthreadex(NULL,0,  (unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *))T2,NULL,0,(unsigned int*)&val2); // create thread
    sprintf(SemName, "ThreadSem_0x%x",val2);
    hThreadSemaphore2 = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 5,(LPCWSTR) SemName);  
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess(); 
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry I tried to reformat the code but think I might have screwed up your question... will try and undo it! Sorry!

Comment: OK think I've corrected my mistake...

Comment: @Flup: Heya flup, the edit that's been made isn't how I formatted... did you peer review or edit?

Comment: @Jimbo I voted to accept but other reviewers didn't realize where all the extra code was coming from so I have rolled back to the original version and cleaned that up.

Comment: Why two semaphores by the way?

Comment: @Flup. The two semaphores are used so that the tasks run in lock-step, so the interleaving of tasks is always 1,2,1,2,1,2... when one is running the other is always waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create both semaphores before you create (and run) your threads. I'm assuming `_beginthreadex` starts thread running immediately...

If you check the return codes from the semaphore takes and gives, on the runs where it deadlocks, do you get an errors returned? I'm thinking that threads could have started before all semaphores are created...

Comment: Thanks, i created the Semaphores before the thread being created. Seems it works fine now. I tried running it 10 times, all the time, the out put got printed from the threads. Thanks a lot Jimbo for making the code more readable way and giving the answer.

Comment: @Gilly: Hi Gilly, could you accept the answer if it's working for you please? Cheers.